# How to read JSON sent from server?

Tags: c#, json, events, http-post, subscription

I have a Subscription service to which I have subscribed POSTing a JSON to the subscription URI in C# code. Now during the subscription, the server sends me some JSON. How do I read that JSON?

Any idea on how to go about it?

The JSON which I had posted:

```
{
    "Destination": " ",
    "EventTypes": [
        "StatusChange",
        "Alert"
    ],
    "HttpHeaders": {},
    "TTLCount": 2,
    "TTLUnits": "minutes",
    "Context": "My context string"
}
```

Here, i think we need to fetch the JSON from the URL which should be mentioned in the Destination parameter.
Could you help me in what could i be giving for the Destination URL?

Comment: Hi. Did you try making a POCO for that response and then using a JSON parser like Newtonsoft's for example?

Comment: You use a JSON serializing library, like Newtonsofts JSON.NET